# How to handle uncertainty introduced by low resolution measurements

Tags: error-analysis, metrology

When trying to convert a continuous variable (running time of a piece of code) into a quantised one (s on a clock), I've been trying to work out the effect of instrument resolution on the uncertainty of my measurement.

What I'm trying to do is measure how long a task takes using a timer with resolution $r$, and then come up with the probability distribution for that value. I'm assuming the actual length of the task $x$ is random, anywhere from zero to infinity, and can start at any time. All I know is when the task started and when it finished, as reported by my low resolution timer.

For example, imagine my timer has a resolution of one day. My measurement will be something like

> Test started on Monday and finished on Tuesday, so had a duration $\hat{x}$ = 1 day

what's the uncertainty?

---

If we think about the limits: The task could have been running from Monday morning until Tuesday evening, in which case it took up to 2 days duration. Or the task could have started just before midnight on Monday and finished just after, in which case the task may have been a few seconds long. So for a task starting on Monday and ending on Tuesday, $\hat{x}$ = 1 day, the actual duration $x$ I believe to be uniform in the region 0-2 days

Here's the confusion: If x was indeed less than a day long, maybe an hour, then my measurement might have been

> Task started and ended on Monday, $\hat{x}$ = 0 days

Thinking again about limits, this puts $x$ in the range **0-1 days**. So for the same $x$, $\hat{x}$ is different depending on whether the task started in the morning or the evening, and in these two instances the uncertainty of the measurement is different!

In graphical form, here's what I mean:

[image: Single Day]

The same task is shifted a little on the timeline. If the task crosses a boundary between days (runs over midnight) then it has a duration of 1 and uncertainty/ uniform probability distribution of $\pm1$, if it occupies a single cell then it has a duration of 0, and a uniform probability distribution in the range 0-1. I think 0 is a special case though since you can't have negative durations, so instead consider a longer task:

[image: Multiple days]

#### My question:

Given the same task can have different measured duration owing to the resolution of the timer, or the same duration can be measured for 2 very different tasks, what is the probability distribution for actual duration $x$ given a measured duration $\hat{x}$ and instrument resolution $r$, when

- $\hat{x} = 0$
- $\hat{x} = N \cdot r$ for positive integers $N$

Or rephrase how you see fit

Comment: I strongly recommend getting a copy of "Data Reduction and Error Analysis" by Bevington.  That will help you better form your questions.   Now in your case, the standard deviation of a value with resolution bin size X (in your case, one day) is well-known to be sqrt( bin_size^2/12)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for the suggestion, I'm keen to get some more canonical knowledge in this area  - although any improvements I'd like to hear. As for the bin size stuff; that works for a uniform rectangular probability distribution - what I'm assuming for a single measurement. However for taking the difference I'd argue the probability distribution is not uniform.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If you measure a duration of 2 days, it could be caused by a task that took just over 1 day, or just under 3 days. However these extremes are very unlikely since they require the task to start at very specific times, like just before midnight. So for a measurement of 2 I think the probability distribution for underlying value will peak at 2 and fall off gradually towards the extremes of 1 and 3 days. Maybe triangular? That would give a variance of 1/24 not 1/12 I think?

Comment: so long as the distribution is uniform, the uncertainty is defined purely by the bin size.   If you know the distribution is different, you just have to calculate the appropriate integrals over your distribution to get the variance (aka square of standard distribution)